# Show last state of boolean field from elastic in grafana's stat panel

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have elastic index that get a new document every X minutes, which one of its fields is a boolean field that determines whether a server is up or down (true or false, and no prometheus can't help because the logic behind it is complex and already implemented by another team).

I'm trying to create a simple grafana **stat** panel, which will be green or red based on the value of the most recent document we get from the query.

I tried many transformations and options with no success. I don't mind using value mapping or another solution as long as I can get red/green panel (and I also tried this direction with no success)

The only way I managed to do it is using logs table, using group by transformation using the first timestamp and is_up field, and only showing the is_up value using organize fields.
But this solution is ugly and bad, and for some reason I couldn't color the cell even after using value mapping (true->1, false->0)

**EDIT:** I managed to do it (and will post it as answer if no one will be able to improve it), I used logs metrics and with the calculation I chose first, and by using filter by name transform I chose to only show to is_up field.
But now my problem is that I cannot color the fields based and the state. I tried using value mapping which helped me before, but now for some reason it doesn't work at all.
**EDIT2:** It worked by changing the true/false values to 1/0 and then everything worked as I wanted in the panel. I'll post this solution as an answer after the bounty ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my solution as an answer because this is the best way I managed to solve it, and no one answered it yet, so I hope it would help other people in the future:

The solution:

1. Pick `logs` as your metric
2. Use `first` as the calculation in Display options within Panel options
3. Add `Filter by Name` transformation, and only show the field you're interested in (is_up in my question)
4. If you want to color the panel correctly you will have to change the way you create new documents in your index- instead of using a `boolean` field change it to `int` and just use 0 as false and ` as true, than you will be able to use thresholds correctly.
5. If you still want to show true/false or up/down as the stat of the panel use `value mapping` and change 1 to up/true and 0 to down/false.